# Dataset on coronavirus government countermeasures (per country/region/city?)

Tags: data-request, medical, government, covid19

I am looking for a machine readable dataset of what country has enacted what form of lockdown on what date, and possibly the "type" of lockdown (international travel/national and international travel, restaurants, schools, public offices etc.).

---

**Note:** See [this question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16185/1511) for aggregate case counts

Comment: HTH: https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm. Not "data", though...

Comment: Thanks @philshem for interest and assigning bounty. Please note that the answer who received the bounty is providing a dataset on only a dozen country and not up to date - while the ACAPS and two Oxford groups datasets cover all countries in the planet, and are up to date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are now some fairly complete and up to date such datasets. 
An Oxford University group - Future of Humanity Institute - has gathered these data:

https://storage.googleapis.com/static-covid/Containment%20measures/COVID-19%20containment%20measures.zip

Almost simultaneously, a different department, the Blavatnik School of Government from the same institution, has published a somewhat different take on the same data:

https://www.bsg.ox.ac.uk/research/research-projects/oxford-covid-19-government-response-tracker

Both datasets are meant to be kept up to date. And of course there is the already mentioned dataset above by the Assessment Capacities Project (ACAPS), an independent information provider:

https://data.humdata.org/dataset/acaps-covid19-government-measures-dataset

Answer (score 9):

We started a worldwide crowdsourcing data collection on policy measures, including lockdowns at the admin1 level (region) and the country level. Currently we coded data for ~13 countries and are continously expanding. You can access the data here:
[Collaborative Google Sheets on Policy Measures Against Covid19](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tYfD3vvSEaW3Cq9-UZoDtlKIfaMMVJq8XnV9XJUdK3s/edit?usp=sharing).

These data are free to use for anybody. *We rely on user contributions to this data. Anybody is asked to add to the data. For suggestions for more fundamental changes.*

If you use these data, please consider adding or updating at least on country in the list.

Comment: Glad that you like this. Please consider giving feedback on our classification or adding to the data. Thanks

Comment: thanks for sharing! It seems very similar to the Future of Humanity Institute intiiative. However there are only a dozen countries highlughted here. Maybe it would make sense to join forces with Oxford?

Answer (score 7):

At this point Wikipedia will have most of the information but not yet machine readable. For a broad data-request on global lockdowns of varying degree, and for an ongoing event, I can't image a machine readable dataset yet.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic

One example would be using school closures, for which there is a separate page and lists/tables of countries.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_of_the_2019%E2%80%9320_coronavirus_pandemic_on_education

Comment: Thanks-I just specified that I am looking for a machine readable one - sorry for the omission

Answer (score 6):

What about this database? It includes government measures...

[**ACAPS COVID-19: Government Measures Dataset**](https://data.humdata.org/m/dataset/acaps-covid19-government-measures-dataset)

> The COVID-19 Government Measures Dataset puts together all the measures implemented by governments worldwide in response to the Coronavirus pandemic. Data collection includes secondary data review. The researched information available falls into five categories: - Social distancing - Movement restrictions - Public health measures - Social and economic measures - Human rights implications Each category is broken down into several types of measures. ACAPS consulted government, media, United Nations, and other organisations sources.

Comment: This is an excellent resource .. comprehensive and well documented.

Answer (score 4):

Actions taken in Switzerland are available with machine-readable CSV

Repo 1: https://github.com/zdavatz/covid19_ch#data-on-the-measures-taken-against-covid2019

Repo 2: https://github.com/baffelli/covid-2019-measures

> *Here we collect a timeline of all containment and public health measure taken in the course of the covid2019 pandemics.*

Columns in the CSV are:

- date_implemented
- date_lifted
- measure
- unit
- level
- source

Answer (score 2):

There is the Official Government Italian COVID Dataset on Github daily updated (16:00 UTC) in JSON and CSV for Country, Region and Province:

https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19 (The fields are in Italian but there is an English description)

The hard lock-down start the 10th of March 2020 with this rules:

https://www.ilpost.it/2020/03/10/coronavirus-guida-inglese/

Starting from 25th of March 2020 all other “non-essential” activities (industries, public and private offices etc) was closed.

Answer (score 2):

- Wikipedia has a page on COVID-19 related curfews and lockdowns: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_related_curfews_and_lockdowns (thanks [Willeke](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/27650/willeke) for pointing to that resource).
- https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/international-travel-document-news/1580226297.htm has a list regarding travel restrictions for all countries in the world.

Both come as unstructured texts.

Answer (score 0):

Another dataset for control measures for US States are being collected here

Database: https://tinyurl.com/statepolicies

More info in this tweet and its replies: https://twitter.com/JuliaRaifman/status/1245416835211812875

> Interested in #COVID19 policy research? We created a database of the dates of state policy changes for researchers to start investigating health & economic effects #epitwitter #econtwitter

Answer (score 0):

And now another site, that collects many (MANY) different sources

https://lukaslehner.github.io/covid19policytrackers/