# Covid-19 policy response data

Tags: medical

Is there data on government measures taken to fight Covid-19? Lockdowns, school closings, etc?

Comment: Duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16244/1511

Comment: See this answer https://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/16261/1511