# Data of covid-19 test per day, per country

Tags: data-request, medical, covid19

Similarly to a recent [question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16244/dataset-on-coronavirus-government-countermeasures-per-country-region-city) on lockdowns, wonder if there is a machine-readable dataset of covid-19 testing per country/state/region. Testing rate largely affects the official number of infected, and thus of apparent fatality (Case Fatality Ratio). This data would be needed to explain mortality differences between region/nations.

Comment: I use data.humdata.org, but, as below, there are many sources.

Comment: https://ourworldindata.org/coronavirus-data-explorer?zoomToSelection=true&minPopulationFilter=1000000&casesMetric=true&dailyFreq=true&aligned=true&perCapita=true&smoothing=7&country=USA~GBR~CAN~AUS~IND~DEU~FRA&pickerMetric=location&pickerSort=asc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OurWorldInDate site (that has excellent coverage of data around the pandemic) has asked the question two weeks ago

https://ourworldindata.org/covid-testing

and now provide an answer:

https://github.com/owid/covid-19-data/tree/master/public/data/testing

Answer (score 2):

Data for Italy:
https://github.com/pcm-dpc/COVID-19/tree/master/dati-andamento-nazionale

You just need the file: dpc-covid19-ita-andamento-nazionale.csv

It is updated every day in the evening (gmt+1)