# COVID level of lockdown by state by month or week?

Tags: usa, time-series, covid19, state

Looking to compare my salespeople's sales to their ability to reach their customers due to lockdown measures. Where would I look to see each state's official response/level of lockdown by week or month through 2020?

Comment: duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16244/1511

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Oxford COVID-19 Government Response Tracker](https://github.com/OxCGRT/covid-policy-tracker/) appears to have the data you want.  The dataset covers the whole world and is day-by-day, so you'll need to do some processing to extract just the US state data and merge or filter it to produce week-by-week or month-by-month data.

Answer (score 3):

An excellent source of Covid related data can be found at covidtracking.com. I wouldn't be surprised if you could find what you are looking for there. You can also download complete datasets from covidtracking.com/data/api.

They have been gathering data since the beginning in the US. Every day, 7 days a week, dozens of volunteers scour dept. of health websites, city/state/county government web sites and more to get the most up-to-date data available. Many doctors and scientists are part of their volunteer base too.

There are dozens, if not hundreds, of websites, news outlets, and more using their data and you even see their data presented on tv by major news stations.

I know this to be true for I have also been helping them to collect data since May. I hope this helps.

Rick

Added 12/09/20

Hi,
The covidtracking site is the most complete of any site that I have found. Sorry you didn't find what you were looking for.

Today I found a resource that might help with what you are looking for. I didn't see anything broken down by state as you are wanting it but there is a table, by state, with URLs to various government and other websites.

To get the granularity you are looking for I suspect you will need to scour each individual state for their specifics.

COVID-19 State Reopening Guide
https://www.multistate.us/issues/covid-19-state-reopening-guide

COVID-19 State and Local Policy Dashboard
https://www.multistate.us/research/covid/public

Rick

Comment: That is a really great resource for hard numbers and yes, does seem to cover the whole period. But it doesn't include the measures used by states and when they were implemented/removed.

Comment: Added more information to my original post.