# covid-19 clinical data or statistics

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, covid19

I don't even know if this is the best place to ask it but, as a statistics community think somebody here may know something. I am wondering what kind of databases and data are actually available regarding covid-19 infection, especially epidemiological and clinical characteristics.

Is there any source that published available characteristics/clinical data for the affected patients?

I tried to search the web for it but found no actual downloadable DB or similar

Thank you so much in advance fro any help

Comment: Hi @cccnrc, if you search through the site you'll find a number of posts related to COVID-19: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=covid-19

Comment: Duplicate? https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/16251/1511