# Is COVID-19 *projection* data publicly available?

Tags: medical, covid19

I'm making a geographic visualization of some important COVID-19 data in the US (confirmed cases and deaths, mainly.) I've been asked to include projections for the future, and I'd prefer it if they were from real, epidemiological sources. Googling around, though, I can only find relatively high-level reports on these projections (like the PDF of the famed Imperial College study.)

Ideally, I'd like some of the raw projection numbers underlying these studies, with as much geographic granularity as possible (I recognize there's a sacrifice of precision as the model granularity increases, but I'm happy to accept it if I can find the data.)

Comment: There are two questions asked already https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/covid-19-clinical-data-or-statistics (detailed data) and https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16185/covid19-coronavirus-case-data-count-of-cases-and-deaths (aggregate data) ... do one of these do the job?

Comment: I think case projections aren’t covered in the existing questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHE (Institute for Health Metrics and Evaluation, University of Washington) is one resource providing COVID-19 projection data. Seems to be US States only.

https://covid19.healthdata.org/projections

> COVID-19 projections assuming full social distancing through May 2020
>
> As the pandemic progresses, we are working to incorporate new data about the virus in the US.

Get the data: http://www.healthdata.org/covid/data-downloads

[image]