# Corona virus - summary of analyses

Tags: data-request, covid19

There are many sites that contain some relevant data about the coronavirus. The question has been asked [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16185/covid19-coronavirus-case-data-country-summary-data) and [here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16251/covid-19-clinical-data-or-statistics), however, these are usually time-series data and some case-level data.

Is there however a summary of it? Someplace that summaries all of the odds ratio of various demographic attributes of the chance of death/hospitalization and the like? Or any other relevant metric?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A partial answer, with hospitalization, for Germany only:

[image]

Help finding data with hospitalization rates in other countries would be welcome:
what percentage of hospital beds are occupied by covid patients,
what % of critical care, how long ?

.csv, code and some notes are under [gist.github.com/denis-bz](https://gist.github.com/denis-bz).

Answer (score 1):

#### [Worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-death-rate/)

This site provides the summaries all of the odds ratios of various demographic attributes of the chance of death/hospitalization.

You can explore different sections of the [website](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/coronavirus-cases/)