# Is it possible to download worldometer COVID-19 country data?

Tags: csv, covid19

I want to download the raw data for COVID-19 cases in [Sweden](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/sweden) but can't find anywhere on [worldometer](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/) to do it.

Does anyone know how to download the data as a csv file?

Comment: The data is available as JS dictionaries in the HTML source, which is pretty easy to scrape: view-source:https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/country/sweden/ - search "'Daily Cases" in the source code.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it is possible (from a read of [faq](https://www.worldometers.info/faq/), [about](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/about/)) there seems to be no way to download data.

Have a look at alternative data sources in [another question](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/16185/covid19-coronavirus-case-data-country-summary-data), but of these I would use the [Johns Hopkins github data](https://github.com/CSSEGISandData/COVID-19/blob/master/csse_covid_19_data/csse_covid_19_time_series/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv), which is a daily updated csv.

Answer (score 2):

to clear philshem's comment up for the non-programmers, here's what to do:

Right click anywhere and open inspect element. Then click the search button at the top right and with the top search bar (not the one that says filter), search daily cases. Click the third one; the list of numbers below is the dataset.

Typing that makes it sound really obvious so sorry if everyone already knew that but it took too much trouble shooting for me to get it!